# Proper way to bundle and consume webpack-built typescript library?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm started using typescript recently and cannot understand how to build a typescript library which would be used in another typescript module using webpack.

Also this library and is intended to run in browser.

Currently I have ended up with following structure and build output:

```
lib
├── build
│   ├── typings // tsc output with declaration:true
│   │   ├── Bar.d.ts
│   │   └── Foo.d.ts
│   └── lib.bundle.js //webpack bundle file
├── src
│   ├── Bar.ts
│   └── Foo.ts
├── bower.json
├── package.json
└── tconfig.json
```

**webpack configuration**:

```js
webpackOptions = {
    resolve: { extensions: ['', '.ts'] },
    module: {
      loaders: [{ test: /\.ts$/, exclude: [/node_modules/,/out/,/.*\.d\.ts/],include:[/\.ts$/], loaders: ['ts-loader']}]
    },
    ts:{
      compilerOptions:compilerOptions
    },
    output: {
      library:"mylib",
      libraryTarget:'commonjs',
      filename: 'mylib.bundle.js'
    }
  }
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir":"out",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "typings/global",
    "build"
  ]
}
```

And **Foo.ts** for example:

```ts
export class Foo{
    foo(){}
}
```

**Bar.ts**:

```ts
import {Foo} from './Foo'
export class Bar{
    public foo:Foo = new Foo();
}
```

So I have following build output:

- webpack bundle
- typescript declaration for each file

And the questions are:

- How can I import/consume this library via bower in another browser application(which will use typescript with webpack too)?
- Which import syntax would be used in application consuming this library(e.g. `import .. from` or `require` )?
- Maybe I shouldn't use webpack for bundling library at all?

**UPDATE:** Used NPM to manage local dependencies between typescript modules without bower as suggested by @basarat and everything worked fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Maybe I shouldn't use webpack for bundling library at all

This is what I recommend. Leave the bundling up to the the top level application consumer.

e.g here is a module `csx` https://github.com/basarat/csx you can use in TypeScript. You can see its not bundled in any special way. Its *just a node module*. If the person wants to use it in the browser **bundling is on them**

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html

Comment: I am also going the path of just providing the compiled .js files and leave it up to the application developer to figure out how my libs should be bundled in to their application.

Comment: Ok. This is the way to go with node modules when library consumed via NPM by node application.
What should I do to use TS library in application using bower?
I already have an existing TS application with dependencies managed in bower and ambient typings definitions.
Is it possible to import  library via NPM and bundle with application with webpack/broserify?

Comment: Have a look at http://young-programmer.life/2017/02/creating-a-typescript-library-using-webpack/